# Cannot Scale Text Size for Different Devices

Tags: java, android, text-size

I am having issues scaling text for different devices. I have recently ran app testing on Amazon Web Services Device Farm and was shocked to see that certain smaller device are pulling from my values-sw600p folder. I have the folder set up as follows:

Code Line:

```
mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_button_answer_text_size));
```

sw-600dp folder:

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="center_indentation">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="poll_question_text_size">22dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_left">160dp</dimen>
<dimen name="radio_button_answer_text_size">14dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_bottom">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="answer_label_text_size">9dp</dimen>
<dimen name="answer_value_label_text_size">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="vote_count_label_text_size">13dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Here is a screen shot of text size I am getting on a Google Nexus 5:

[image]
The "Test Answer" text should be similar in size to the Test Poll Question text. It appears that the Google Nexus 5 is pulling from my sw-600dp folder.

At the end of the day, I am looking for the simplest way to scale a text size on different devices. I have read that setting a TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX in the setText() method is one approach, but that approach does not appear to be working either. Also, I am a bit confused whether I should be using SP or DP in my dimens folder.